# Bubble sort for Listbox not working C#

Tags: c#, wpf, sorting, listbox

I have a program where the user can input number into a listbox the user also gets and option to sort the listbox. I am not allowed to use any arrays or containers or list, just modify the items listbox property and use converting and parsing. I want to do this through a bubble sort, although the numbers that only displays on the listbox once the sort button is clicked is 0,1,2,3,4...

```
private void sorted()
    {       
       int a = Convert.ToInt32(lstHoldValue.Items.Count);
        int temp = Convert.ToInt32(lstHoldValue.Items[0]); 
        for (int i = 0; i < a; i++)
        {
            for (int j = i + 1; j < a; j++)
            { 
                if (Convert.ToInt32(lstHoldValue.Items[i]) > Convert.ToInt32(lstHoldValue.Items[j]))

                {
                    temp = Convert.ToInt32(lstHoldValue.Items[i]);
                   (lstHoldValue.Items[i]) = Convert.ToInt32(lstHoldValue.Items[j]);
                   (lstHoldValue.Items[j]) = temp;
                }
            }
        }
        lstHoldValue.Items.Clear();
        for (int i = 0; i < a; i++)
        {
           Convert.ToInt32(lstHoldValue.Items.Add("\t" + i));  
        }
    }
```

How users enter values to the listbox

```
   private void btnAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{         
    string text = "\t" + txtInitialise.Text;
        if (this.index < MAX_ITEMS) // MAX_ITEMS or 10 
        {
            Convert.ToInt32(lstHoldValue.Items.Count);
            int dnum;
            if (int.TryParse(txtInitialise.Text, out dnum))
            {
               Convert.ToInt32(lstHoldValue.Items.Add( "\t" + dnum));
                index++;
                txtInitialise.Text = "";
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! It looks like you need to learn to use a debugger.  Please help yourself to some [complementary debugging techniques](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).  If you still have issues afterwards, please feel free to come back with more details.

Comment: Sorry, I'm pretty new to all this i still don't know whats wrong :(

Comment: can you help Joe C?

Comment: Did you read the article?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like you are just adding the index of the List item to List, that's the reason it always returning 0 - 4 (5 elements). Updated the answer to sort only using the list items.

**Updated:**

Maximum items allowed to insert into listbox:

```
const int MAX_ITEMS = 10;
```

Your sorted method was working correctly, though you cleared the listbox in the end, so you lose the sorting, as swapping is done inside the listbox using the for-loop:

```
private void sorted()
{
    int a = Convert.ToInt32(lstHoldValue.Items.Count);
    int temp = Convert.ToInt32(lstHoldValue.Items[0]);

    for (int i = 0; i < a; i++)
    {
        for (int j = i + 1; j < a; j++)
        {
            if (Convert.ToInt32(lstHoldValue.Items[i]) > Convert.ToInt32(lstHoldValue.Items[j]))

            {
                temp = Convert.ToInt32(lstHoldValue.Items[i]);
                (lstHoldValue.Items[i]) = "\t" + Convert.ToInt32(lstHoldValue.Items[j]);
                (lstHoldValue.Items[j]) = "\t" + temp;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Add button click:

```
private void btnAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int index = 0;
    if (index < MAX_ITEMS) // MAX_ITEMS set to 10
    {                
        int dnum;
        if (int.TryParse(txtInitialise.Text, out dnum))
        {
            lstHoldValue.Items.Add("\t" + dnum);
            index++;
            txtInitialise.Text = "";
        }
    }
}
```

Sort button click:

```
private void btnSort_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    sorted();
}
```

Comment: Hi Abdul, thanks for your kind help, although I am not allowed to use any containers or lists, only allowed to modify the items listbox property and to use parsing and converting.I had done this program working with an array but now have to re-do it :(

Comment: I changed the code completely, it works but no entirely sure if its within the scope of my work. How would you do it?

Comment: Do you need to keep tab spaces?

Comment: OMG thanks Abdul! you're a real brother. We should be friends :))