# Bubble sort is not working

Tags: c#, winforms, bubble-sort

Currently the user is able to input numbers into the ListBox, and I want the ListBox to be sorted by the bubble sort below when a sort checkbutton is clicked. However, it only outputs the index number e.g. 0,1,2,3... I am not allowed to use any array or containers just the items property and parsing and converting.

```
private void sorted()
{
    int a = Convert.ToInt32(lstHoldValue.Items.Count);
    int temp;
    for (int i = 0; i < a; i++)
    {
        for (int j = i + 1; j < a; j++)
        {
            if (Convert.ToInt32(lstHoldValue.Items[i]) >
                Convert.ToInt32(lstHoldValue.Items[j]))
            {
                temp = Convert.ToInt32(lstHoldValue.Items[i]);
                (lstHoldValue.Items[i]) = Convert.ToInt32(lstHoldValue.Items[j]);
                (lstHoldValue.Items[j]) = temp;
            }
        }
    }

    lstHoldValue.Items.Clear();
    for (int i = 0; i < a; i++)
    {
        Convert.ToInt32(lstHoldValue.Items.Add("\t" + i));
    }
}
```

Comment: Well, at the end you clear your list and then start adding indices from i to a. What exactly are trying to do with the last for cycle?

Comment: You're clearing your Listbox (so losing it's values in the process) and add loop indexes (the `i` in your last loop) instead ; Also `Items.Count` is already an int, no need to convert it

Comment: Also algorithm is I think wrong - bubble sort means reviewing collection as long as you don't make any change of order; You are looping collection once and in inner loop rest of collection - it doesn't seem as proper implementation of bubble sort.

Comment: Yeah sorry, i was meant to delete that clear()  line out. If i do so, it'll only display the index numbers 0,1,2,3,.. etc. Im just not sure how to sort my listbox without using any containers or array, only using the listbox item properties.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Bubble sort for Listbox not working C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40698626/bubble-sort-for-listbox-not-working-c-sharp)

Comment: I think it's kinda *rude* to ask the exact same [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40698626/bubble-sort-for-listbox-not-working-c-sharp) as you did 12 hours ago.

Answer (score 0):

If the item in the ListBox is not an integer, then it is sorted as zero (0).

This sets `bubbleUp` to true indicating that a swap has been made in the list box. This variable is used to indicate that a swap has/has not been made in the last comparison. Entering the `while(bubbleUp)` sets `bubbleUp` to false to indicate that no swaps have been made. Then a loop through each item in the list box  to compare adjacent items and swap if needed. If a swap is made, `bubbleUp` gets set to `true` indicating that the sort is not finished. `bubbleUp` only needs to be set once in the for loop to indicate another iteration is necessary. `CheckItem` is the conversion from string to integer. Hope this helps.

```
private void sorted()
{
  bool bubbleUp = true;
  string temp = "";
  while (bubbleUp)
  {
    // bubble up adjacent values
    bubbleUp = false;
    for (int i = 0; i < _ListBox.Items.Count - 1; i++)
    {
      if (CheckItem(_ListBox.Items[i].ToString()) > CheckItem(_ListBox.Items[i + 1].ToString()))
      {
        temp = _ListBox.Items[i].ToString();
        _ListBox.Items[i] = _ListBox.Items[i + 1];
        _ListBox.Items[i + 1] = temp;
        bubbleUp = true;
      }
    }
  }
}

private int CheckItem(string inItem)
{
  int value;
  if (int.TryParse(inItem, out value))
    return value;
  return 0; 
}

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  sorted();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is more like a Bubble sort algorithm:

```
    private void BubbleSort()
    {
        int a = lstHoldValue.Items.Count;
        for (int i = 0; i < a - 1; i++)
        {
            var k = 0;
            for(var j = 1; j < a - i; j++)
            {
                if (Convert.ToInt32(lstHoldValue.Items[j]) < Convert.ToInt32(lstHoldValue.Items[k]))
                {
                    var temp = lstHoldValue.Items[j];
                    lstHoldValue.Items[j] = lstHoldValue.Items[k];
                    lstHoldValue.Items[k] = temp;
                    k = j;
                }
                else
                {
                    k++;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

It will sort the numbers in the `Items` collection of your `lstHoldValue listBox` control